C++ How to properly handle trim with ICU of NBSP
I have the following trimming function
std::string trim(const std::string &input)
{
    icu::UnicodeString unicodeString = icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF8(input);

    unicodeString.trim();

    std::string result;
    unicodeString.toUTF8String(result);

    return result;
}

It works just fine for regular spaces, but if I add NBSP it doesn't handle it properly. Am I supposed to handle that myself? I thought NBSP was part of the Unicode standard - meaning the ICU library should handle it.

The trim method in ICU's UnicodeString class doesn't handle all types of whitespace, like NBSP. To fix this, we can use a more complete trimming function:

std::string trim(const std::string &input)
{
    icu::UnicodeString unicodeString = icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF8(input);

    int32_t start = 0;
    while (start < unicodeString.length() && u_isUWhiteSpace(unicodeString.char32At(start))) {
        ++start;
    }

    int32_t end = unicodeString.length() - 1;
    while (end >= start && u_isUWhiteSpace(unicodeString.char32At(end))) {
        --end;
    }

    icu::UnicodeString trimmedString = unicodeString.tempSubStringBetween(start, end + 1);

    std::string result;
    trimmedString.toUTF8String(result);

    return result;
}

The issue was that u_isWhitespace doesn't cover all whitespace characters. u_isWhitespace follows Java/ICU definitions and excludes characters like U+00A0 (NBSP), U+2007 (Figure Space), and U+202F (Narrow NBSP).
Instead, I used u_isUWhiteSpace, which checks if a character has the White_Space Unicode property. This includes all types of whitespace characters.
source:
https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a6bca1d0c13a2ac376f6f52c653fcac38
https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a2ba8fcc9070c57a70aa491d911a6743b
